# Number of actions to access equipment

Tags: actions, equipment, the-dark-eye, the-dark-eye-4

After it came up in the last session, i wanted to try and find Information on how long it takes to draw a weapon (from a scabbard, from your back) or a shield (from your back) or things from a pouch/backpack. I searched my (4.1) books, but the only thing I found was the special ability quickdraw (Schnellziehen) mentioning how long it takes for someone with the ability. Where in the (german, 4.1) books can I find this Information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always glad to see a TDE-Question. Sorry that I only know all the terms in german.

The answer to the question lies on page 54 of the "Wege des Schwerts" / Way of the Sword (?), where all different kinds of actions in combat are listed. The following things are mentioned:

- Drawing a Weapon from Belt-, Arm-, Leg- or Chest-Scabbards: 1 Action
- Drawing a Weapon from a Back-Scabbard: 2 Actions
- Putting a Shield from the Back to the Arm: 5 Actions
- Orientation: 2 Actions, 1 with "Alertness" ("Aufmerksamkeit")
- Putting a Weapon away: Twice the amount of time to draw it.
- Getting and drinking an Elixir from a belt pocket: 10 Actions (5 if you manage a FF-Check)
- Getting and drinking an Elixir from a backpack: 20 Actions or more (half if you manage the FF-Check)
- Tactics: 1 Action
- Position: 1 Action
- Catch Breath: 1 Action
- Activate Artifact: 1 free Action
- Drop Weapon: 1 free Action
- Drop to the Floor: 1 free Action

For anything else, the book recommends your GM to set a time, and to let any TaP* (leftover points of the Ability check) reduce that time.

I hope this helps!